# How to Implement One to Many in DRF

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am Designing a Model

```py
class Timer(models.Model):
    total_time = models.FloatField(default=5)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class WatchTiming(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField("authentication.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    current_timer = models.ForeignKey(Timer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="current_timer")
    previous_timers = models.ForeignKey(Timer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="previous_timers")
```

and serializer for this model is

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Timer, WatchTiming


class TimerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Timer
        exclude = ("id",)


class WatchTimingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    current_timer = TimerSerializer(required=False)
    previous_timers = TimerSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = WatchTiming
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        watch_timing = WatchTiming.objects.create(user=self.context["request"].user, current_timer=Timer.objects.create())
        return watch_timing
```

WatchTiming is a table that is used to store user watch time

> current_timer stores today's timer
> when the day expires current_timer values are added in the previous_timer and the current_timer value is replaced with the default

Now My issue is how can I create one to many relationships, I already have written relationships but its not working

**I have been stuck on this for 4 consecutive days.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subserializer, just like you did with your `TimerSerializer`s:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Timer, WatchTiming


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User  # authentication.User
        fields = (
            'id',
            'username',
        )


class WatchTimingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    current_timer = TimerSerializer(required=False)
    previous_timers = TimerSerializer(read_only=True)
    user = serializers.UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = WatchTiming
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return WatchTiming.objects.create(
            user=self.context['request'].user,
            current_timer=Timer.objects.create(),
        )
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so from the `Timer` model to the `WatchTiming`
> model in this case. Therefore it (often) makes not much sense to name it the
> same as the forward relation. You thus might want to consider renaming the <s>`current_timer`</s> relation to `watch_timings`.

Answer (score 1):

By using `SerializerMethodField` you can create one to many relationships.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = "__all__"


class WatchTimingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        current_timer = TimerSerializer(required=False)
        previous_timers = TimerSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
        user = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    
        class Meta:
            model = WatchTiming
            fields = "__all__"
         def get_user(self, obj):
             data = User.objects.filter(id=obj.id)
             return UserSerializer(data, many=True).data
```